# Не могу понять задачу на C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

[image: Задача]

Здравствуйте, готовлюсь к олимпиаде по информатике. Во время решения данной задачи столкнулся с тем, что не понимаю откуда берётся такой результат. Написал программу которая находит по одному значению второе, а потом их S. Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    setlocale(0, "");

    int  width = 0, height = 0, S = 0, K = 0;
    double part;

    cout << "Введите число K = " << endl;
    cin >> K;

    while (!(K >= 2) || !(K <= 100))
    {
        cout << "Число должно быть не меньше 2 и не больше 100!" << endl;
        cout << "Введите число K = " << endl;
        cin >> K;
    }

    if (K <= 50) {
        width = K;

        part = width / static_cast<double>(5);

        height = part * 3;

        // cout << part;
    }
    else {
        height = K;

        part = height / static_cast<double>(3);

        width = part * 5;
    }

    S = width * height;

    cout << "S = " << S << endl;
}
```

Comment: while (K < 2 || K > 100) - более читабельно

Comment: Ещё более читабельно: `while (K < 2 || 100 < K)`. Надпись можно положить на числовой ряд: `... K ... [2, 100] ... K ...`. Теперь очевидно что мы хотим расположить `K` вне отрезка `[2, 100]`.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вы перепутали отношения. Если `K <= 50`, то это ширина, а значит длина -- `K / (3 / 5)` или же `K * (5 / 3)`. Во-вторых, поскольку вы работаете с целыми числами, необходимо все операции деления выполнять в самом конце, чтобы не потерять дробную часть.

Алгоритм примерно такой:

- частично найти вторую сторону, умножив известную на числитель отношения (Если на вход дали 8: `8 * 5`, результат 40);
- найти произведение стороны на найденное число (`8 * 40`, результат 320);
- найти результат целочисленного деления полученного на предыдущем этапе числа на знаменатель отношения (`320 / 3`, результат 106);
- найти остаток от деления полученного на предыдущем этапе числа на знаменатель отношения (`320 % 3`, результат 2)

Дальше только вывод. Если результат последнего шага -- `0`, то вывести только результат предпоследнего шага. Если нет, то вывести результат предпоследнего шага, последнего и знаменатель отношения

UPD: Дополнение от @ГерманБорисов: В задаче сказано про "минимальный возможный знаменатель", но так как и 3 и 5 являются простыми числами, шаг сокращения дроби можно пропустить.

Comment: В задаче сказано про "минимальный возможный знаменатель", но так как и 3 и 5 являются простыми числами, шаг сокращения дроби можно пропустить.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, да, верно, забыл об этом написать, спасибо!

Comment: А зачем нам остаток от деления и вообще, зачем вы проводите все эти операции, соотношение нам было дано разве не для того, что бы мы нашли высоту или ширину, а потом отталкиваясь от этого нашли его площадь, или это я ничего не понял?

Comment: @СергейМиронин, в задаче сказано вывести ответ в виде простой, а не десятичной дроби. В первом же примере ответ 106 целых и 2/3

Comment: А.. Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так, что сложного?
Допустим мы ввели натуральное число `num = 75` => length,тогда получаем примерно следующее: `(num * num * width)/length;`. И наоборот — то же самое, только меняем местами `width <-> length`.

Comment: Я просто учу С++ чуть больше недели)

Comment: Так тут ведь дело уже не в языке,если,конечно это не первый ЯП)